# Spaces in test method names when targeting multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I really love the ability of Kotlin to add spaces to method names, [which is a well-documented approach commonly used to make test names more readable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html):

> In tests (and only in tests), it's acceptable to use method names with
>   spaces enclosed in backticks. (Note that such method names are
>   currently not supported by the Android runtime.) ...
>
> ```
> class MyTestCase {
>     @Test fun `ensure everything works`() { ... }
>     ...
> }
> ```

I have adopted them vigorously in a new library I'm developing, targeting the JVM. My tests show up beautifully in IntelliJ, and all is well.

Now, I am trying to port this library to be [multiplatform (targeting both the JVM and JavaScript)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html). When I add a test with spaces I receive the following Kotlin compiler error when Gradle `build` runs `compileTestKotlin2Js`:

> Name contains illegal chars that can't appear in JavasScript identifier

**Should I remove all spaces from my test methods, or is there another way to have the best of both worlds?**

In addition, regarding the limitation that "such method names are currently not supported by the Android runtime", is this a real limitation? As long as I can run my tests on the JVM, I can still use the tested library (containing no spaces in any of the methods) targeting an Android runtime, correct?

Comment: Technically you can use the `@JsName` annotation on each test to specify an alternative name that would be used for the JavaScript backend, but specifying two different names for each test isn't really a productive way of working.

Comment: @yole, Regardless, a good option to be aware about! Thank you for the comment. However, it seems like `JsName` is not accessible from a `common` library?

Comment: As far as I understand, it will be at some point.

Comment: I found more elaborate documentation on how to use `@JsName` [on Kotlin Academy](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/testing-common-modules-66b39d641617). By using `expect` and `actual` you can use `@JsName`. @yole, feel free to post this as an answer, I feel it is a suitable one for those who do not mind the method name duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tests that are in a common or a JavaScript module, you are correct, you'll have to give up the nice names using backticks, and resort to the more traditional `ensure_everything_works` or similar. For tests that are JVM specific, you can continue to use backticks and spaces.

This includes JUnit tests for code that you're later planning to run on Android. The only limitation there is that you can't use spaces in tests that actually have to run in an Android environment, but the unit tests (I assume JUnit) run on your dev machine's JVM so they'll still work with spaces in the identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript **doesn’t allow tests with spaces** and we would get an error once we would try to run it in JS module. There is a simple solution: Kotlin/JS provides annotation **JsName**, that can be used to specify the actual name of a function in compiled code. It is Kotlin/JS annotation, so it cannot be used in commonTest module. Although, we can define expected declaration in the test sources of commonTest module like so:

```
expect annotation class JsName constructor(val name: String)
```

Make it kotlin.js.JsName annotation on jsTest module:

```
actual typealias JsName = kotlin.js.JsName
```

Define some annotation that will be ignored for the other target platforms:

```
actual annotation class JsName actual constructor(
    actual val name: String
)
```

Now, we need to annotate our tests:

```
@JsName("SendAcceptHeaderTest")
@Test
fun `send accept header`() = runTest {
    //...
}
```

With such declarations, we can freely run our tests on all platforms.

Comment: `@JsName` [_can_ be used in common](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-name/index.html): that is the exact use case. I considered using it, but this notation is extremely redundant, so just opted for underscores.

Comment: It's worth it for many to have the test names visually appealing.

Comment: For me it works with Kotlin 1.4.0 even in common mode with hierarchical structure enabled. Even without the typealias that's already present in 1.4.0.

Comment: Any way to have a line break with that Sir ?

Comment: I decided to use `@JsName` with a dumb name as this name doesn't really show up anywhere. `@JsName("testX")` is doing the trick for me.